# Variable declaration in Swift REPL must have initial value

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop, variable-declaration

Studying Swift grammar declaration of closure. I'm having a problem with:

```
let add: (Int, Int) -> Int 
add = { (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int in
    return a + b
}
```

error:

> variables currently must have an initial value when entered at the top level of the REPL
>   var add: (Int, Int) -> Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift does not have separate variable declarations without assignments (assigning nil to an optional would be the closest thing), so the easiest fix would be:

```
let add: (Int, Int) -> Int = { (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int in
   return a + b
}
```

As correctly pointed out by the commenters and as noted in the error message, my claim is only true at the top level of the Read-Eval-Print-Loop (REPL).

Comment: This is not completely true. Swift does have separate variable declarations without assignment. You just cannot do that at the top level. You could do that without problems in a console application or in a function.

Comment: This applies *only* to the REPL. Perfectly legal: https://gist.github.com/woolsweater/503c12cd91b9e9573e0ddadec7b02c0d